# Using encoded string in database table

Tags: java, database, database-design, primary-key

I wish to define a primary key in mysql database table. I was planning on encoding provided string value to BigInteger.

Note: The string being converted is not made up of numeric characters. e.g `Athletic` is a valid string. Its BigInteger equivalent is `4716509524531636579`.

The longer the string, the longer I believe will be the length of the BigInteger generated. This can lead to limitation while defining data type of primary key. Storing such huge numbers as blob is an option but AFAIK, we cannot use blob as primary key.

Any alternatives on how to generate a fixed length number that be generated from string and used as primary key in database?

Comment: Perhaps a hash ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use the real string value? Or create an identity, auto-generated number and store the string field as a normal column? You can create a unique constraint / index if you need that.